# Share variable between different functions in one class PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently making a WP widget and i am stuck with this. I want to pass a variable from one function to another. The functions are inside the same class.

```
     class jpen_Custom_Form_Widget extends WP_Widget {

      public function __construct() {
       $widget_options = array(
        'classname' => 'custom_form_widget',
        'description' => 'This is a Custom Form Widget',
        );

         parent::__construct( 'custom_form_widget', 'Custom Form Widget', $widget_options );

           add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_mail', array( $this, 'deliver_mail' ) );
           add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mail', array( $this, 'deliver_mail' ) );

          } 
         //...
        function deliver_mail() {     
          //How to access $instance['email'] value;
        }

        public function form( $instance ) { 

          $emailReceiver = '';
          if( !empty( $instance['email'] ) ) {
            $emailReceiver = $instance['email'];
          }
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not make `$instance` a member of your class?

Comment: You can make it a property of the class, or you can pass the dependency as normal.  If you make it a property you may want to check that it was set inside the `deliver_mail` method.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be to make the variable into a class-level variable. (In this case it can probably be private). Of course in order for the deliver_mail() function to be able to use it, the form() function must have been executed first.

```
class jpen_Custom_Form_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    private $emailReceiver;

    function deliver_mail() {     
      //How to access $instance['email'] value;
      print_r($this->emailReceiver); //example of using the value
    }

    public function form( $instance ) { 

      $this->emailReceiver = '';
      if( !empty( $instance['email'] ) ) {
        $this->emailReceiver = $instance['email'];
      }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: What can i do if deliver_mail() function have been executed before form() function?

Comment: @J.Domino you'd have to write some code in the deliver_mail() function to check if the variable was populated and if not, throw an error. Or, re-design your code to work in a better way - I don't know the context, but maybe the deliver_mail() function could accept the value directly, or you could accept the value in the constructor instead (so it's there when the object is first created),or something else. It's hard to say what's best without knowing the use case etc but those are some options for you.

Comment: this is deliver_mail() function - https://pastebin.com/9cMWj5LC. It sends email via PHPMailer. The form() method is a form in the widgets section where the user can use to fill out the email reciever.

Comment: Ok so is there any reason the form() method doesn't directly call the deliver_mail() function itself? You still haven't really given me a full context. TBH I don't think I need it though. I've answered the question which was given. Whether or not that's the right design for your scenario is a separate issue. I've given you some ideas about how to re-design it...you need to think through your use case and the process you need to go through, and structure your code appropriately so that it can't send an email without the address being present.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem... if it helped you to resolve the original question, please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

Make a class variable and set it's value to `$instance['email']` to share it in another function.

```
class jpen_Custom_Form_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    // make a class variable
    public $var;

    function deliver_mail() {     
      //How to access $instance['email'] value;

      //Use is any where with $this
      var_dump($this->var);
    }

    public function form( $instance ) { 

      $emailReceiver = '';
      if( !empty( $instance['email'] ) ) {
        $emailReceiver = $instance['email'];
      }

        //set class variable value
        $this->var = $instance['email'];

    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you, I will take care of that in future too... 